# Populate textarea from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, modal-dialog

I have a table that's generated from a Knockout.JS observable array. As you can see, in each row I have a bootstrap button in the last column in which I call a modal. In the modal I have text area's that I want to populate with the selected row. I've tried data-bind="value: Number" but it will not populate the modal. Any advice?

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: notes" >
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Number"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Date"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Time"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: User"></td>
        <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editnotemodal" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Edit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would make the context of the modal dependent upon something like a selected row ko.observable.  This would allow you dynamically share context.  An example -

**In your view -**

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: notes" >
    <tr data-bind="click: setActiveRow">
        <td data-bind="text: Number"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Date"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Time"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: User"></td>
        <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editnotemodal" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Edit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<div class="modal" data-bind="with: activeRow">
    <h2 data-bind="text: User"></h2>
    <textarea data-bind="value: Number" />
</div>
```

**In your view model -**

```
var activeRow = ko.observable();

function setActiveRow (sender) {
    activeRow(sender);
}
```

Now whenever you have an activeRow and the modal is showing it is properly data-bound back to your table row.

Comment: What is the sender variable in your example?

Comment: sender is the current context that is passed to the function.  In JavaScript, it would represent what 'this' is.  In my example it would be the row that is being sent, so if you console.log'd it you could see the properties on it.